# how to send the data to the table view depending on the condition

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, latitude-longitude

The following is the code which i am using to check whether the latitudes and longitudes are within the 100 meters radius,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [dataArray count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Person *temp = (Person *)[self.persons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = temp.strName;

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}



- (void) readDataFromDatabase{

    sqlite3 *database;
    persons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){

        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from sdata";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                pID = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);
                //                NSLog(@" Id : %d",pID);
                pName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSLog(@" Name : %@",pName);
                pAdd = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSLog(@" Address : %@",pAdd);
                pPh = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 3);
                NSLog(@" PhoneNo : %d",pPh);
                pCp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];
                NSLog(@" ContactPerson : %@",pCp);
                pLat = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];
                NSLog(@" Latitude : %@",pLat);
                pLong = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 6)];
                NSLog(@" Longitude : %@",pLong);



                Person *temp = [[Person alloc]initWithID:pID name:pName address:pAdd phone:pPh contactperson:pCp fLat:pLat fLong:pLong];
                [persons addObject:temp];
                [temp release];

            }

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}



- (void)startTest
{
    for(int j=0;j<[persons count];j++){

        Person *arr = [persons objectAtIndex:j];


        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",arr.fLat,arr.fLong,arr.strName] ;
       // NSLog(@" data in array : %@", s);


#define COORDS_COUNT 1
#define RADIUS       100.0f

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[COORDS_COUNT] = {
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([arr.fLat floatValue], [arr.fLong floatValue ]),


    };

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat floatValue], [longt floatValue]); 
    CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:center radius:RADIUS identifier:@"Banashankari"];



    for (int i = 0; i < COORDS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = coords[i];

        NSString *coordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",coord.latitude, coord.longitude];
        [dataArray addObject:coordString];

        if ([region containsCoordinate:coord])
        {
            NSLog(@"location %f, %f is within %.0f meters of coord %f, %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude, RADIUS, center.latitude, center.longitude);
            [resultArray addObject:coordString];
            NSLog(@"data within 100 meters %@",resultArray);
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"location %f, %f is not within %.0f meters of coord %f, %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude, RADIUS, center.latitude, center.longitude);    

        }
    }

}
}
```

In my log I am getting the result as expected only, i.e, it shows which latitude and longitude are within the 100 meters and which latitude and longitude are within the 100 meters, but in my table view it is showing all the latitudes and longitudes, but i need to show only the latitude and longitude which comes within the 100 meters only, where i am doing the mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sarah Please check the code i have Updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the method `numberOfRowsInSection` you are taking **count of dataArray** and in method  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are loading

```
Person *temp = (Person *)[self.persons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = temp.strName;
```

it should be

```
cell.textLabel.text = [dataarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Try this. If not solved,tell me.

Comment: are...use resultArray instead of data array and retain resultArray after [resultArray addObject:coordString];

Comment: its throwing the following exception Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'

Comment: in numberOfRowsInSection also take resultArray

Comment: it is showing the latitude and longitude which are within the 100 meters. Now how can i display the corresponding name of those latitude and longitude which are in the database.

Comment: ya i got the solution but I just need to display the corresponding name for the latitude and longitude. Custom cell means should i call to the array or what?.

Comment: what do you mean by that? use custom cell for the same.

Comment: I tried using the custom cell, but it is still displaying the latitude and longitude instead of there corresponding name.

Comment: how r u writing cell.textLabel.text?

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: sorry not error, it is showing the last latitude and longitude's corresponding name,not the expected name.           cell.textLabel.text = pName;

Comment: datatype of pname is NSString

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [nsstring stringwithformat:@"%@",pname]; also check if pname contains data or not. write like this

Comment: I used the above line it is throwing the following exception Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSString stringwithformat:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x26a6d0' and i also checked the data in pName it is containing only last value

Comment: I got the output i just changed one line, i.e [resultArray addObject:arr.strName]; in the if-else statement in startTest.